# Jetty is converting Empty String in null

Tags: jsf, web-applications, jetty, web.xml

Jetty is converting Empty String as null. I want to prevent this behaviour. I tried this

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

But still result is same. If anybody have any workaround.